# O que motivou a Microsoft a mudar o estilo de aplicações consoles no .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, estilo-de-codificação, console

Recentemente a Microsoft lançou o .NET 6, e com ele chegou uma "novidade" que me deixou um pouco confuso: as aplicações console têm um código base bem mais "mínimo".

Por exemplo, antes do .NET 6, esse era o código padrão ao criar uma aplicação de Console:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Após a atualização, o código é agora:

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Ainda é possível criar métodos dentro deste "arquivo de script", usar diretivas de `using` e outras funções do código padrão.

Mas eu não entendi por que ela fez isso. Por que uma empresa encurtaria o código de seu *framework*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na verdade não é só nas aplicações do tipo console, pode ser de todos os tipos, claro que esse tipo ficou mais curto que as outras que precisam inicializar um *framework*.

Há uma tendência geral de facilitar para quem está entrando no mercado, e até de simplificar o que pode ser simplificado. C# está competindo com linguagens de *script*, então ela tem que parecer um pouco mais simples, mantendo todo potencial que tinha antes. Por alguma razão as pessoas acham que escrever um pouco menos de código torna a linguagem melhor, mesmo em aplicações grandes.

De fato quando C# é usada como *script* isso é vantajoso, e já tem quem usa, principalmente usando um [Notebook](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive). Para aplicações a vantagem real é pequena

Na verdade a pergunta deveria ser "por que alguém não encurtaria seu código se puder?". Código curto é mais fácil de ler, costuma ser mais expressivo e mais fácil de dar manutenção. Assusta menos para quem está acostumado com linguagens menos cerimoniosas. Antes não podia tanto quanto agora.

Havia um mito que C# precisava ser muito verboso, o que nunca foi verdade, mas era um pouco, agora compete com qualquer linguagem em boa parte dos cenários. Se quiser mais simplificação aí tem que ir para F# que até códigos mais complexos continua tão ou mais curto que as linguagens de *script*.

Usando isso como exemplo instrui as pessoas usarem assim, mostra que quem não quer fazer código curto está usando fora do padrão.

Na verdade o padrão do Visual Studio é esse aí, mas dá para fazer um código mais simples ainda (depende de criar um outro *template* ou ter um arquivo extra de configuração global):

```
Write("Hello World!");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/MinimalHelloWorld.cs). Não dá para colocar nos IDEs *online* porque elas não estão preparadas para isto ainda.

Um exemplo de código para web (dá pra tirar o `WebApplication` igual fiz acima):

```
var app = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World");
app.Run();
```

Isso é todo o código, não é só um trecho.