# Existe alguma forma de mudar o novo layout da IDE VS

Tags: c#, software

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma configuração para deixar o primeiro exemplo que ja vinha pronto na IDE na nova versão do VISUAL STUDIO?

```cs
using System; //Importando o namespace System

namespace CursoCSharp.Fundamentos //Divisões Lógicas
{
    class PrimeiroPrograma //Arquivo principal da aplicação
    {
        public static void Executar() //Método principal
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Primeiro ");
            Console.WriteLine("Programa");
            Console.WriteLine("Terminou!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Nova forma de aplicação de um código C#;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi, está usando qual IDE? me parece o Code. Tenta utilizar o visual Studio, que por lá ele ja cria a cs formatada.

Comment: oi @paulohenrique estou usando o vscode, porem fiz o mesmo procedimento no Visual Studio (IDE). La ele so me retorna a mesma linha de comando.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40271/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/534133/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome disso é [top-level statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements), é um recurso que foi adicionado ao C# 9.

Os top-level statements só funcionam para o método `Main`, o que quer dizer que você só poderá ter um arquivo neste formato (sem declarar namespace, classe e método) em todo o seu projeto. No fim das contas o compilador vai gerar todo o código padrão pra você, isso é só um facilitador (se chama [*syntax sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)).

No .NET CLI não existe nenhuma opção para criar o arquivo no formato antigo, mas pode haver [uma alteração no .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/19672). Caso precise da versão mais verbosa, você mesmo pode editar o arquivo para adicionar as informações.

Comment: Perfeita explicação Jéf Bueno.

Answer (score -2):

Parece que as outras linhas de código estão implícitas, o Console.WriteLine() não funcionaria sozinho. É alguma configuração da IDE. Mas esses códigos só vem como exemplo, quando você cria um projeto novo vai ter que digitar o seu próprio código de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta está muito errada.